# How to use ng2-ckeditor as inline?

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have used ng2-ckeditor but i need to use it as inline, So how can i used that as inline ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor

I am using angular-cli for angular2 development.

Comment: Can you put someof your code and what exactly you want ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342556/cannot-set-property-dir-of-undefined-ckeditor-in-angular2

Answer (score 2):

To do inline in ng2-ckeditor,
change ckeditor.component.js in ng2-ckeditor/src

change  this.instance = CKEDITOR.replace(this.host.nativeElement, config);
to  this.instance = CKEDITOR.inline(this.host.nativeElement, config);
This worked in my local system but facing issue on production

But after replacing this i am getting the
" Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined "

I have tried setting the base_path in index.html but didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

First understand the difference between **classic** ckeditor and **inline**.

**Classic ckeditor** uses an IFrame, which `ng2-ckeditor` wraps and provides an angular component for, as in:

```
<ckeditor></ckeditor>
```

That creates an angular 2 component inside your template and inside that is an iFrame. This iFrame loads its own CSS (contents.css by default from ckeditor CDN). This means your editor instance is isolated from your websites css.

**Inline ckeditor** uses the html contenteditable attribute on an HTML element (eg. a div or textarea - note that not all elements are [supported](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-editable)).

Since this is now a div in your page, your website styles will apply inside that editor (eg. if the user presses enter, thereby creating a `<p>` element in the editor, whatever `<p>` css is being applied on your page will apply to the users `<p>` in the editor).

So, first create the div in your template:

```
<div id="inline-editor1" contenteditable="true">
</div
```

Now you need to tell CKEDITOR about that div.

So At the top of your component before @Component decorators, add this line:

```
declare var CKEDITOR: any;
```

Finally in your ngOnInit, tell CKEDITOR about your div:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.setConfig();
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline( 'inline-editor1' );    
  }
```

Now when you click inside that div, you get the inline ckeditor toolbar.

Docs [here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_inline).

**CAVEAT - PLEASE NOTE**

This method means you will not be able to use [(ngModel)] to bind to the contents of the inline editor (as you can with ng2-ckeditor). You will have to use standard javascript to extract the [contents of the editor for saving](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_savedata).

[Here is a plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/KnTkMo/) that shows the ng2-ckeditor and the inline editor. Notice how the inline editor is NOT bound to any model.

Comment: Essentially you need a div (or textarea) with an id. When you want to show the inline editor you call CKEDITOR.inline(<id>) and ensure disableAutoInline is set to true. Here is a plunker of angular1 doing this: https://plnkr.co/edit/YUOYGa?p=preview  Notice also that this is really just using javascript to create the editor and there is no model binding to the editor contents - just like the CAVEAT I gave.

Comment: Inline editor is part of ckeditor.  ng2-ckeditor is the classic ckeditor and it also works in Angular4. But ng2-ckedtior does not support INLINE mode. For that you just need an ID and 2 lines of javascript to create it.

Comment: This is good , but inline ckeditor I am unable to source code button, how to configure it

Comment: The inline ckeditor does not have a source code button as far as i know.

Comment: with out source code there is no use of inline ckeditor, is there any other alternative

Comment: Froala has one: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/always-visible To get the 'source' you need the 'html' button. See this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGJaGQ?editors=1111

Comment: NOTE: if you use Froala in SaaS software you need a business license. And you cannot use Froala in Open Source projects.

Comment: TinyMCE is open source, has inline mode also: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/ Click Tools menu to get access to the 'source' option.